Change aplication icon problem in flutter
Hey guys i want to change my app icon in flutter, i see a couple of tutorial and documentation told me to add launcher icon in pubspec.yaml .
but after I add it in pubspec.yaml and run flutter pub get the icon doesn't change at all.
i try this code :
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.14.2"

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21


Did you do everything the README says, like dart run flutter_launcher_icons:generate?

run in terminal after flutter pub get :-
dart run flutter_launcher_icons:generate

I wrote an article on this topic that you may find useful


Add the package flutter_launcher_icons
Update the path, the code should look something like this; ( in pubspec.yaml)



flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/tap.png"




run flutter pub get
run flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
Verify the changes in either Android or ios directory, the file ic_launcher.png should have an updated icon.

